# General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint [ Laravel 5.8 ]

Tags: laravel, foreign-keys

i want to add two `foreign key` in one Model but its seem doesnt work and return Error like this

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table `expenses` add constraint `expenses_shop_id_foreign` foreign key (`shop_id`) references `shops` (`id`))

and below is my Model

```
<pre>
    Schema::create('expenses', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('shop_id');
        $table->date('date');
        $table->string('description');
        $table->double('amount');
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->foreign('shop_id')->references('id')->on('shops');
    });
</pre>
```

My shop Model

```
<pre>
    Schema::create('shops', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('description');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
</pre>
```

is there any way to make it work? Thanks in advances...

Comment: You should use `index()` while defining a `foreign key`. `$table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id')->index();` `$table->unsignedBigInteger('shop_id')->index();`

Comment: @SalmanZafar still, doesnt work, bro..

Comment: are you refreshing the database or adding this column with new migration?

Comment: yep, bro i run `php artisan migrate:fresh` @SalmanZafar

Comment: use `php artisan migrate:refresh` instead

Comment: I'm guessing that the `id` in `shops` is declared something other than `bigIncrements('id')`

Comment: i dont know why its still doesnt work @SalmanZafar

Comment: can you post your shops and users table migrations?

Comment: @N69S Nope bro id in shops is `$table->bigIncrements('id')`

Comment: is `shops` migration being run before `expenses` migration ?

Comment: @N69S nope bro..

Comment: Are you using sqlite or mysql?  if mysql, what version?

Comment: @kerrin mysql Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.27, bro..

Answer (score 0):

unsignedBigInteger will create unsigned integer in database but bigIncrements will create signed integer so you need to make them the same type.

**either you change**:

shops table:

```
$table->bigIncrements('id');
```

expenses table:

```
$table->BigInteger('shop_id');
```

**or** :

shops table:

```
$table->increments('id')
```

expenses table:

```
$table->unsignedInteger('shop_id');
```

Comment: sorry if you used the first solution it's wrong, maybe I was not clear in my answer I'll edit it. use $table->BigInteger('shop_id'); if shops table already migrated

Comment: $table->bigInteger('shop_id'); // lower case b